# Error writing metadata in Artifactory 5.5.1

Tags: artifactory

We have jfrog artifactory pro version 5.5.1

We recently started getting below error:

Error is happening only when we try to publish to one specific repo , other repos are working fine when same artifact is published.

We have this custom groovy code sitting in the plugins which we think is causing this issue , but it was working fine before upgrade seems like.

```
import org.artifactory.exception.CancelException
import org.artifactory.repo.RepoPathFactory
import org.artifactory.util.StringInputStream

storage {

  afterCreate { item ->
    def SourcePath = RepoPathFactory.create('stage-release', item.repoPath.path)
    def DestPath = RepoPathFactory.create('release', item.repoPath.path)
    if (item.repoPath.repoKey == 'stage-release') {

        echo " ID is " + item.repoPath.id
        if (repositories.exists(DestPath))
            {
            echo "FOUND the artifact in the release repo so no need to copy"
            } else {
            echo "MISSING artifact in the release repo so copying it over"
            repositories.copy (SourcePath, DestPath)
    }
    }

  }

}


def echo(str) {
  log.warn "########################### " + str;
}
```

Error while writing metadata for .: ConcurrentModificationException

```
2018-01-12 03:57:58,582 [art-groovy-plugins-reloader] [WARN ] (o.a.a.p.e.ExecutePluginImpl:184) - Overriding existing execution with name. 'getProxiesList'.
2018-01-12 03:57:58,593 [art-exec-330376] [ERROR] (o.a.r.d.DbStoringRepoMixin:270) - Couldn't save resource, reason:
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap$ValueSet$1.checkForComodification(LinkedHashMultimap.java:364) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap$ValueSet$1.hasNext(LinkedHashMultimap.java:370) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap$WrappedCollection$WrappedIterator.hasNext(AbstractMapBasedMultimap.java:480) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.addon.plugin.GroovyRunnerImpl.getPluginActions(GroovyRunnerImpl.java:90) ~[artifactory-addon-plugins-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.addon.plugin.GroovyRunnerImpl.execPluginActions(GroovyRunnerImpl.java:79) ~[artifactory-addon-plugins-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor254.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy228.execPluginActions(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.addon.plugin.PluginsAddonImpl.execPluginActions(PluginsAddonImpl.java:52) ~[artifactory-addon-plugins-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.repo.interceptor.PluginsInterceptor.afterCreate(PluginsInterceptor.java:60) ~[artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.repo.interceptor.storage.StorageInterceptorsImpl.afterCreate(StorageInterceptorsImpl.java:65) ~[artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor451.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.afterCreate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.repo.db.DbStoringRepoMixin.invokeAfterCreateInterceptors(DbStoringRepoMixin.java:391) ~[artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.repo.db.DbStoringRepoMixin.saveResource(DbStoringRepoMixin.java:230) ~[artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.repo.db.DbLocalRepo.saveResource(DbLocalRepo.java:158) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.saveResourceInTransaction(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:1779) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor455.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.saveResourceInTransaction(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.saveResource(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:1749) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.saveFileInternal(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:586) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor637.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201) [spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.saveFileInternal(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.artifactory.maven.AbstractMetadataCalculator.saveMetadata(AbstractMetadataCalculator.java:61) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator.createVersionsMetadata(MavenMetadataCalculator.java:354) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator.calculateAndSet(MavenMetadataCalculator.java:184) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator.calculateAndSet(MavenMetadataCalculator.java:200) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator.calculateAndSet(MavenMetadataCalculator.java:200) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator.calculateAndSet(MavenMetadataCalculator.java:200) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator.calculate(MavenMetadataCalculator.java:152) [artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataServiceImpl.calculateMavenMetadata(MavenMetadataServiceImpl.java:81) ~[artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataServiceImpl.calculateMavenMetadataAsync(MavenMetadataServiceImpl.java:56) ~[artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor467.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.artifactory.work.queue.WorkQueueImpl.invoke(WorkQueueImpl.java:109) ~[artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.work.queue.WorkQueueImpl.doJobs(WorkQueueImpl.java:82) ~[artifactory-core-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.artifactory.schedule.ArtifactoryConcurrentExecutor$RunnableWrapper.run(ArtifactoryConcurrentExecutor.java:104) ~[artifactory-storage-common-5.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

Comment: What is the name of this user plugin? Can you try to remove it, reload your user plugins, and check that your error goes away?

Comment: plugin was writting in house .. we can try removing it .. issue is that it gives us ability to not overwrite existing artifacts ( which can be done by not giving delete permissions ) but without failing the build. ;-( kind of in house requirement .. this is for maven..

Comment: Frankly, if I were you, I would just remove the plugin, make sure the problem goes away, and then implement this feature by working upon the existing user plugin provided by Artifactory at https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/c7e7bad773aaba072cb1937e11c867dd8013f8b2/security/preventOverride/preventOverride.groovy